# Convert BIT DATA To String Java

Tags: java, db2

I have a variable `OBJECT_ID` stored in DB2 as `OBJECT_ID VARCHAR() FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL`.

How can I retrieve the `String` value stored in it?

I have tried following code to convert `Binary` to `String` in Java as:

```
String str = resultset.getObject("OBJECT_ID").toString();
int charCode = Integer.parseInt(str,2);
String str1 = new Character((char)charCode).toString();
```

But it throws following:
 `NumberFormatException: For input string : "[B@475e586c"`

Sure the String is not an Integer but how can I retrieve the `String` value of a `VARCHAR() FOR BIT DATA` from DB2 in my java program?

Comment: Please don't use too much capital and bold.

Comment: Looks like that this needs [tag:db2].

Comment: try this `String str = resultset.getString("OBJECT_ID");`

Comment: @YCF_L Now it returns a String as "0464145d43B3fd4c932bf480df3b4a32" and same exception

Comment: you said `Sure the String is not an Integer` so the question is, why you parse it as an int?

Comment: Could you try some cast, e.g `SELECT CAST(OBJECT_ID as VARCHAR(1024) FOR SBCS DATA) as STR_OBJECT_ID FROM` ? Maybe you could also try with `MIXED` instead of `SBCS`.Then retrieve it with `resultset.getString("STR_OBJECT_ID")` .

Answer (score 2):

As "[B" of `toString` indicates the type `byte[]`, the following should be possible:

```
byte[] b = (byte[]) resultset.getObject("OBJECT_ID");
```

Then there is the problem that `String` is for (Unicode) text, not binary data. A `char` is two bytes encoded in UTF-16.

You could try to abuse String as:

```
String s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // Bad idea.
```

This depends on OBJECT_ID.

Normally binary data could be encoded as text as Base64, using 64 ASCII chars as "digits."

```
String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b);
```